# HELM _helpers.tpl : How to check if template block is defined in _helpers.tpl?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to check if a template block has been defined in _helpers.tpl.

Sudo Code:

```
{{- if "sample.color" template is defined }}
color: {{ include "sample.color" . }}
{{- else }}
color: {{ .Values.color }}
{{- end }}
```

Is there a way to achieve `{{- if "sample.color" template is defined }}` in helm?